# ForEach loop not the same as printed in CLI?

Tags: powershell, outlook, scripting

When I type '

```
$Listboxcal= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 

add-type -assembly “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook” | out-null
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.oldefaultfolders?view=outlook-pia
# Calendar = olFolderCalendar = 9
$calendar = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(9)

# get today's calendar items!
 $cItems = $calendar.Items | Where-Object {$_.Start -ge $(Get-Date) -and $_.Start -le $(Get-Date).AddDays(1)} | select Start, Subject.
```

' the CLI prints perfectly the date/time/subject title

however when I add '

```
$Listboxcal= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$Listboxcal.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) 
$Listboxcal.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(230,270) 
$Listboxcal.Height = 150
[…]
ForEach ($calendars in $cItems) {[void]$Listboxcal.Items.Add($calendars)} '
```

I only get "@(Start=05/05/2019 11:30:00; Subject=}" printed. Ideally I would like Time start and Subject printed to list box. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Never explicitly filter items in your code - it is very inefficient. Always use Items.Find/FindNext or Items.Restrict, especially if you want to expand the recurrences.

See the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences